# Angular Ng repeat with checkboxes - uncheck a particular checkbox from a button click

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes - that populate a tag textarea - when the user remove a tag I also want to uncheck the checkbox

When the user navigates away and come back the checkboxes should maintain the state they were in - ie check against the tags and see if they match

So I need

1. Click state to pouplate tags
2. initial check to see if the checkbox should be checked or not - the scope of the checkboxes is killed by navigating away unless I rootScope it maybe?
3. Delete tag unchecks the check box
4. Only 5 checkboxes in a list can be checked the 6th would return no.
5. Needs to be a select all with above taken into account

I am really quite lost in how to architect this at the moment

going from click to change to model to checked....

many thanks for any help

Comment: You should at least give it a try so you have some code to show and work with. Try taking one problem at a time instead of them all at once :).

Comment: This angular directive should do the trick, or at least put you on the right tracks to implement your own solution :

[https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

Answer (score 1):

try to do the next thing - create an object { clicked : true, label: label}
when you goes throught ng-repeat you have an object to render and state, when somebody delete label - you should just add whole object to handler and there change checkbox state tie to needed element.

P.S. If you add some code we can work with your stuff.